# WordPress - 404 error when passing args URL

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, custom-post-type

I have made a custom post "projects" that works fine, but I need to filter projects with parameters in the URL.

Like : mywebsite.com/projects?type_project=wealth

But I get a 404 error everytime.

Here is the code in functions.php :

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    
    // do not modify queries in the admin
    if( is_admin() ) {
        
        return $query;
        
    }
    
    
    // only modify queries for 'event' post type
    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'projets' ) {
        
        // allow the url to alter the query
        if( isset($_GET['type_projet']) ) {

        $query->set('meta_key', 'type_projet');
      $query->set('meta_value', $_GET['type_projet']);
      echo($_GET['type_projet']);
            
    } 
        
    }
  // return
  

    return $query;

}


add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

If I try to filter in the **archive-projects.php, it works fine.**
I've tried to **refresh permalinks** too.

If anyone can help me please (:

Comment: Dunno if its a typo in reporting the code but you actually have "type_projet" and "projets" when the correct one should be "projeCts" and "type_projeCt". Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: It's ok, I just translated to english because "projet" is french

Comment: But a "/" was missing in the url, it works fine now :) thx

Comment: Good to know, close this question then :)